# Is there a way to mimic classes in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm currently trying to make a new "class" in Applescript. I know that, without making an application, it is technically impossible.

But I tried to mimic it with an embedded `script`:

```applescript
script specialText
    property value : ""
    on flip()
        return reverse of (characters of my value) as string
    end flip
end script

set x to specialText

set value of x to "Hello World"

x's flip()
```

This works great and returns `"dlroW olleH"` as expected, however:

```applescript
script specialText
    property value : ""
    on flip()
        return reverse of (characters of my value) as string
    end flip
end script

set x to specialText

set value of x to "Hello World"

x's flip() = specialText's flip()
```

This returns `true`.

So my question now is, can I do something like this without making the new variable a reference to the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close. AS doesn’t have classes, but you can create new instances of a script object just by executing the `script` block statement.

Wrap it in a handler like this:

```
to makeSpecialText()
    script specialText
        property value : ""
        on flip()
            return reverse of (characters of my value) as string
        end flip
    end script
    return specialText
end makeSpecialText
```

Create new instances by calling the handler, e.g.:

```
set x to makeSpecialText()
set y to makeSpecialText()
set z to makeSpecialText()
```

You now have three independent instances of the script object bound to `x`, `y`, and `z`, each with its own state.

Apress’ Learn AppleScript, 3rd edition (which I lead-authored) has a chapter on script objects covering libraries (semi-obsolete now as AS finally got native library support in macOS 10.10) and object-oriented programming (reasonably thorough given the length limitations of a 1000-page book).

Comment: Applescript does have built-in classes and classes implemented by applications.

Comment: RE: "AS doesn’t have classes" --  What's your definition? If it does not have classes what is [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-246384) from [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1)?

Comment: AppleScript may have classes in the ontological sense, but not in the OOP sense. e.g. If you ask a string object for its `class` property, what you get is not a `String` class object from which it was instantiated but a symbol, `string`, a name object. As for application “classes”, those are all smoke and mirrors: Apple event IPC is not OOP but RPC plus *queries*. A good example is the typical Text Suite: `character`, `word`, and `paragraph` do not exist as discrete classes, they are merely convenient abstractions for constructing queries that identify ranges in a contiguous character array.

Comment: As to the AppleScript documentation: **it lies**. This is why programmers who understand OOP get so confused and frustrated trying to use AppleScript: AS reuses the familiar jargon of OOP, but maps those terms onto profoundly non-OOP concepts and behaviors. The [appscript documentation](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc_3x/appscript-manual/02_aboutappscripting.html) does a somewhat better job of explaining how AE IPC really works, while still using OO-like syntactic sugar to make writing queries convenient and palatable in an OO language. But it’s an uphill battle to clarify.

Comment: @foo, Thank you for the response to my comment, the information therein was enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

#### Warning: This solution is very memory intensive and is not recommended for doing this! Foo's answer (the accepted one) will most likely fit your needs better.

---

Another way to do it would be to use the `copy` statement:

```applescript
script specialText
    property value : ""
    on flip()
        return reverse of (characters of my value) as string
    end flip
end script

copy specialText to x

set value of x to "Hello World"

log x's flip() = specialText's flip()
log specialText's flip()
```

```
(*false*)
(**)
```

Note that the syntax of the `copy` command is not like the `set`-command. So it is not `copy newVariable to oldVariable` but rather `copy oldVariable to newVariable`.

Comment: **Do not** use `copy`! That does a *deep copy* of the script object itself, plus all of its parent script objects, up to and including the entire script that contains it. Such massive memory copying very rapidly reduces the AppleScript interpreter to a smoking crater. Use a constructor handler: that creates a new instance of the wrapped script object only.

Comment: @foo Thanks for the comment, I will not delete the answer but I will add a disclaimer and point to your question.